# Nest a fixed positioned div inside a fixed positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed positioned `<div>` filled with content. The content is scrollable, but I want to have a "close-button" for that `<div>`, which allways sticks to the top-right. Here is the HTML-code:

```
<div id="job_edit_content">
            <div id="job_edit_contentheader">

                <div id="job_edit_close" onClick="job_edit_close()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
</div>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
#job_edit_content {
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    background-color: #659DBD;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
    z-index: 101;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#job_edit_contentheader {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#job_edit_close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:102;
}
```

But the close-button wont stick to the top-right. It allways scrolls with the content. I tryed sticky-positioning aswell with the same result. Can someone explain me why, please?

Answer (score 0):

Make the position "absolute", not "fixed". If you put up a codepen or some way of replicating I could demonstrate.

Comment: I tryed it with absolute positioning aswell, but it doesn´t stick. thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: You can position your elements relative and adjust the "top" and "right" properties. They're positioned relative to their container and don't move with any scroll. Example: https://codepen.io/ciammarino/pen/PxvWKY.  If it doesn't work, post your code and I'll work through it with you.